# FB.Event.subscribe -> 'comment.create' firing not every time

Tags: facebook, comments, oncreate

I have the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({appId: myapid, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
  alert('Thanks for Your comment!');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(response) {
  alert('You deleted comment!');
 });
};
```

Why it is not firing every time when user (i tested by mine) add or delete comment?

I tested that:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
 alert('123');
}
```

It works perfect.

So the problem in handler to FB.event? How to make it working every time?

Is the difference between opening my_site.com or www.my_site.com? or not? I got only one Appid for my_site.com.

How to handle to every FB.event on page, so i could see all of them and select 'comment.create'?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that something wrong with this code

FB.Event.subscribe

so that you couldn't subscribe comment events to FB. Why don't you double check to make sure that codes work, for example:

```
if (FB && FB.Event && FB.Event.subscribe) { 
/* subscribe code */ 
}
```

or

```
console.log(FB);
```